# My NTFS partition SSD drive became RAW but not in Linux

Tags: command-line, mount, windows-10, users, ntfs

My NTFS became RAW after accessing Users folder on another computer.
I just used my old drive on a second computer, I entered Users folder in root directory C://Users.

The NTFS partition can be mounted in Ubuntu, seen as NTFS partition.
I tried ntfsfix to repair the NTFS.
I also removed the hibernation file

```
ntfsfix /dev/sda3 
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows -o remove_hiberfile
```

Windows RE rescue environment, the command show a RAW partition in healthy state.

[image]

The partition can be mounted in Ubuntu, how to get the RAW back to NTFS ?

Thanks,
Julio.

Comment: This is a Windows problem. Ubuntu doing it correctly is an indicator the issue is within Windows, not perse the ssd itself. If you can access it from Ubuntu I would advice to make a backup before doing anything else. If then nothing else is working format it and restore the backup.

Comment: Windows sees a damaged or overwritten PBR as RAW or unformatted. PBR - partition boot sector NTFS must be Windows. There is  a backup PBR that can be recovered with Windows tools or testdisk. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix If backup boot sector also damaged or identical but invalid, you can use testdisk to write NTFS, but it used to use the old XP standard. You then have to run chkdsk from Windows to convert to newer NTFS PBR.